# check constraint (or something better)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, constraints

The situation: there is a java application that reads data from a DB Oracle.   To simplify, the email field is currently read from a "USERS" table. Now I have to modify the application so that I can read more email addresses but I have no intention to modify all the dozens of already existing queries that refer to this table. The escamotage was to add a "EMAILS" table containing (in addition to PK "id_mailaddr")  only the "id_user" and "mail_address" fields. But because the data are not loaded only by the app but also by other users through the most diverse methods (Excel tables, queries "insert all", sql loader etc.) I have to impose the consistency condition at the database level. And here lies the problem! I do not know Oracle and Pl-sql. How can I write a "check" constraint to impose that, if the "id_user" of the email address that I insert in the new table was already existing in the "USERS" table, the email address that this "id_user" is matched in the table "USERS" must coincide with the matched one in the new table?
For example:

```
USERS                                     EMAILS
id_user  user       email                 id_mailaddr   id_user  mail_address
100      Smith      smith@yahoo.com       1             100      smith@yahoo.com        OK!
101      Brown      brown@gmail.com       2             101      brown@gmail.com        OK!
102      M.Scott                          3             105      scott@hotmail.com      NO!
103      J.Scott    scott@hotmail.com     4             103      j_scott@hotmail.com    NO!
104      P.Scott                          5             104      scotty@aol.com         OK!
```

Comment: Trigger would be a better option in this case i feel

Comment: I don't understand the need for your new table `EMAILS`.

Comment: Thanks! ...but the problem that I don't know oracle remains! how I should to write this trigger?

Comment: the need is to no change the already existing queries!

Comment: Why do the existing queries need to change?

Comment: I don't understand you want to insert a new user? What type of desing patter are you using? Do the application uses any ORM? Why the fear of change a dozen of queries? etc... etc.

Comment: No, on the contrary: I added "QUERIES" because I do not want to change them! Too complicated, I should study all the consequences ... too complex a reverse engineering!

Comment: The fear is due to the fact that the old queries I have not written them and I should spend too much time (which I have not) to decipher them!

Comment: escamotage , I learned a new word today ;-)  If I understand correctly, just add the emails table with a 1-many relationship between users and emails using the user_id.  The new business rule would be to lookup the email(s) using the new email table.  Deprecate the email field in USERS (again, as a business rule) and eventually drop it.  Yes, some queries will need to be changed (by you or someone else), and possibly some app/middleware code

Comment: change some queries is precisely what I wanted to avoid, so I was looking for a check or a trigger (but I'm  not able to write)!
PS - yes, escamotage is not a very common word ... at least in America! it's a word of french origin ... I do not know why it came to my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this trigger code helps -

```
drop table users;
drop table email;

CREATE TABLE users
    (id_user integer, userz varchar2(7), email varchar2(17))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO users (id_user, userz, email)
         VALUES (100, 'Smith', 'smith@yahoo.com')
    INTO users (id_user, userz, email)
         VALUES (101, 'Brown', 'brown@gmail.com')
    INTO users (id_user, userz, email)
         VALUES (102, 'M.Scott', '')
    INTO users (id_user, userz, email)
         VALUES (103, 'J.Scott', 'scott@hotmail.com')
    INTO users (id_user, userz, email)
         VALUES (104, 'P.Scott', '')
SELECT * FROM dual
;



CREATE TABLE email
    (id_mailaddr int, id_user int, mail_address varchar2(19))
;


insert INTO email (id_mailaddr, id_user, mail_address)
         VALUES (3, 105, 'scott@hotmail.com');

insert INTO email (id_mailaddr, id_user, mail_address)
         VALUES (5, 104, 'scotty@aol.com');         

create or replace trigger email_trig
after insert on email
for each row
declare
v_cnt integer := 0;
mail_adr varchar2(64);
e exception;
begin
    if inserting then
        select email, count(*) into mail_adr, v_cnt from users where id_user = :new.id_user group by email;

        if v_cnt = 0 or mail_adr <> :new.mail_address then
            raise e;
        end if;
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error inserting new email:- '||:new.mail_address);
end;
/
```

Comment: t.y.v.m! I fully trust everything you wrote (for me it's like Arabic, Chinese!). I'm going to try now!

Comment: doubt: "after insert on email" you meant the "USERS" email field or an "s" has fallen and you meant the "EMAILS" table

Comment: its a typo .....i created a table called email and wrote this trigger code.

Comment: ok, that's what I supposed! it is instead the error on the exception that I can not solve ...

Comment: When do you get the error and whats the exact message ?

Comment: Already when I write the procedure (I'm using the Toad editor) the message is exactly what I wrote to you.
and then again when I run it tells me: "ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement"

Comment: I have updated the entire code snippet used for verifying and I never faced any issues. It works exactly as expected.

Comment: instead, "select email, count(*)" is not a typo but exactly the field of USERS table...

Comment: ok, I had an illumination! not only I am not an expert in plsql but not even in toad: I kept typing ctrl + enter instead I had to compile!

Comment: exxcellent! it's perfectly runiing! thanx once again!

Comment: Great!!...please accept my answer if it helped you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I've not enough reputation to chat! What I have to do? to click on "votes"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure that no `id_user`, `mail_address` combination gets inserted into the new `EMAILS` table that does not exist in the previously existing `USERS` table?

That only makes sense if it is an interim-design, because you will not be able to put more than one `EMAIL` record for any given `USERS` record.  (I am assuming rows in `EMAILS` must be unique.)

But, if that's the escamotage (+1 for that -- love it!), I think what you are talking about is a **foreign key constraint**:

```
alter table users add constraint users_id_email_u1 
   UNIQUE (id_user, email);

alter table emails add constraint user_id_email_f1 
   FOREIGN KEY ( id_user, mail_address) REFERENCES users  ( id_user, email);
```

This will ensure there are never any `EMAILS` rows that do not match what is in `USERS`.

*However*, it will not ensure the converse!  That is, there could be `USERS` rows that do not have the necessary row in `EMAILS`.  I don't think you asked about that case in your post, but I think that it may prove important to you.  So, I'd suggest that what you *really* want to do is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emails AS
  SELECT id_user, email mail_address
  FROM   users;
```

... and, possibly, this to handle inserts into the `EMAILS` "table"...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emails_trg 
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
  ON emails
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users
  SET    email = :new.mail_address
  WHERE  id_user = :new.id_user;
END;
```

Then, once all your queries are upgraded to use `EMAILS`, replace the view with a real table.

Comment: not exactly Matthew: I would have liked that, inserting an email address in the new EMAILS table, if already the same user (same id_user) has a mail in the old table, the new one must necessarily match; if it does not have any, new mail goes good but, if it does not have that user, but there's another user (I mean always in the old table) owner of that address, goes not good anyway

Comment: The `CREATE VIEW` / `CREATE TRIGGER INSTEAD OF...` part of my solution should handle what you just said.  The only thing you should need to add is a unique constraint on `users.email` and, eventually, one on `emails.mail_address` (later one when you've replaced the `emails` view with a real table.  Or maybe I am still misunderstanding you.